# sed command to regex in multiple lines and replace element in json file

Tags: json, regex, linux, sed

I have a file like this:

`test.json`:

```
{..
}
  "Naveen": {
   "ip_addr": "INET;192.168.1.3;5001",
   "enable": 1,
   "mode": "emulate"
  },
```

I need to regex match `Naveen` and then the next element `mode` and change the mode value from `emulate` to `xyz`.

Failed solutions:

1. `sed '/^Naveen$/{$!{N;s/^Naveen\nemulate$/xyz\nBe/;ty;P;D;:y}}'`
2. `cat test.json | tr '\n' '\r' | sed -e 's/Naveen\remulate/xyz\rBe/'  | tr '\r' '\n'`

What's the mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `sed`,

```
sed '/"Naveen": {/{:loop; N; s/emulate/CHANGED/g; /}/b; b loop;}' yourfile.json
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/"Naveen": {/,/},/{/mode/s/emulate/xyz/}' file
```

Use a range between `{...}` and then focus on the specific string.

Comment: it worked great. now i can parse json file and edit them on the go.